# How can I mount a small front light on my Garmin mount?

Tags: headlights, garmin

I only ride outside during daylight hours, but I like to use a small front flasher light at all times. My current light is the type that attaches to the handlebar with a rubber strap. I recently added a Garmin GPS computer (Edge 530), and the mount is dual-sided. I would love to get a front light setup that uses the bottom Garmin mount attachment point. I've see adapters for GoPro-style mounts, but the only lights I've seen that would work with this are large, nighttime-type lights, not small ones.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your light's lens still work if rotated by 90 degrees?

Comment: "like to use a small front flasher light at all times." - please don't. Solid front light or none at all.

Comment: @whatsisname I read it as a "daytime running light" which is designed to be used in the daylight and doesn't necessarily have that horrid sharp flash.

Comment: To clarify the first point above: I plan to acquire a light. I'm not trying to fit one that I already have. For the second and third comments: As a cyclist _and_ car driver, I don't understand the aversion to blinking lights. I ride in an area where cyclists are not that common on the roads, and any means of making one visible to car drivers seems like a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

There are few rechargeable lights with beam shaping and cut-off that may be mounted upside down. Cat-Eye has two in its G-Volt line that come with GoPro adapters. Lezyne also has a light for hanging mount.

GoPro mounts below Garmin (or other head unit) mounts are fairly common.

Below is a picture of a GVolt 70 mounted to a Sigma mount. No adapters or small parts were needed. Both were compatible out of the box. For beam characteristics and review (in German) see [Boissier-Mohr's webpage](https://fahrradbeleuchtung-info.de/testbericht-cateye-gvolt70)

[image: GVOLT 70 light mounted hanging on GoPro mount]

Comment: Hi @gschenk, this is what I am looking for in terms of how the light is mounted, but I am seeking a "safety" light to use in the day for sport riding/training, rather than a headlight to use at night. I simply do not ride at night. 
For Cateye (e.g. GVolt 70), I did not see any such lights except the ones that use the typical rubber strap (which is what I am trying to get away from).
For Lezyne, the only light I found with a hanging mount is an "e-bike light", a bright, focused light that runs off the e-bike motor. Perhaps you could provide a different link?

Comment: As far as I know all CatEye lights with screw-on clamp use the same mount shoe. Maybe one of the small lights without shaped beam will fit it. The GoPro mount is an aftermarket part.

Comment: Since you need a light for _all times_ I suggest one of the larger ones however. A larger light, like mine, is also good during the day, but unlike a tiny one good at dusk or night. With the mount out there it's not in the way and I take it with me also for daytime rides.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve built this mount out of some aluminium sheet I had lying around:

[image]
[image]

It uses the two existing holes in the bottom of the Garmin mount for two small screws. The heads of the screws are inside of the mount (they barely fit in the space below the topside mounting mechanism). The blue stuff is threadlocker.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is impossible to find exactly the combination of features you need in a small part.

Presumably you need a "quarter turn lock" receiver on top to mount with the underside of your garmin mount, and then below that some kind of round "bar" for the light to strap onto ?

[image: ""]

But instead of the gopro mount in this picture, you want a round bar?

---

EDIT: I threw together two options:

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/3JgP5cwb8DF-garmin-to-strap-on-blinky-light-horiz

[image]

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/4mAmG1TMFpb-garmin-to-strap-on-blinky-light-vert

[image]

In this vertical one I'd suggest you use a ziptie or similar to stop your light dropping off the bottom on a bump.

---

I had something similar when trying to mount an airzound on drop bars to use from the hoods.

In the end I designed and printed my own mount.

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/iBoeeBqNPGq-stub-mount-for-drop-handlebar-for-airzound-horn-235-and-24mm

[image]

Comment: I'm not positive I got the correct lugs for a garmin underneath-connector.  Checking now...

Comment: Hi @Griggie, yes, the first picture is what I was thinking of. I'm trying to find a solution that does _not_ use the rubber-strap approach.

Answer (score 2):

What about a Garmin mount/light combo?

On top is a Garmin quarter-turn mount with a small rechargable front light integrated inside the body.

[image]
<sub>Moon MX GPS Center Mount Rechargable Front Light</sub>

Comment: This is probably my favorite suggestion so far. See this made me also interested in the Cerberus rear light with a wireless link to the Moon front unit. However, the link only supports turning both on with one switch. I would still have to adjust the blinking on both separately. And the Cerberus appears to require removal of the rubber strap for recharging (another no-no from my point of view).